# Why does Shutil.move() rename my capitalized input as the file name in destination?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

```
import shutil


source = 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Folder/{name}.png'.format(name=input("Enter file name: "))

destination = 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop'

dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

I am trying to move a file named 'Green' but by accident, I typed 'GREEN' in caps instead. Everything works but the file is now 'GREEN' at destination. Why is shutil doing that?

Comment: It's an artifact of the way Windows treats file names. It's case insensitive when looking up a file, but when creating or renaming it keeps the case you give it.

Comment: Exactly. This is a Windows thing, not a Python thing.